# creating an array of mui textField

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to create an accordion with a few textfield mui-components in it. I have created a different render function with all the necessary tags and syntax of creating a text field.
Now I want to create an array of text fields, which I could render inside the accordion using a for loop.
Is it possible to do so?
if yes, How do I create an array of object?

[image]

As you can see, the textFields have a few properties/attributes, which reflect inside the accordion. I was wondering if there was a way to create an object of these textFields which could be rendered using a for loop in the accordion. How to convert it into an array on objects?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your inputs object to something like this:

```
inputs = {
  transaction: {
    value: "alto",
    label: "Transaction ID",
    name: "transactionId"
  },
  client: {
    value: "gordo",
    label: "Client ID",
    name: "clientID"
  }
}
```

and show the text fields:

```
Object.values(inputs).map(({name, value, label}) => (
  <FormControl key={label} ...>
     <CssTextField label={label} name={label} value={value} ... />
  </FormControl>
))
```

Or you can do it inside the component of your first image with:

```
const newInputs = useMemo(() => [
    {
      value: inputs.transactionID,
      label: "Transaction ID",
      name: "transactionID"
    },
    {
      value: inputs.clientID,
      label: "Client ID",
      name: "clientID"
    },
    ...
  ], [inputs]);

  ...
  return(
   ...
   {
     newInputs.map((input) => (
       <FormControl key={label} ...>
         <CssTextField label={label} name={label} value={value} ... />
       </FormControl>
     ))
   }
```